# UsageStatsManager is not providing appropriate data for time interval

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

Using `UsageStatsManager` I am trying to get data from 12 am to current time of the day. I have written the following code :

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long beginTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        UsageEvents usageEvents = usageStatsManager.queryEvents(beginTime, endTime);
```

But the provided result is being reset in every 4 or 6 hours; like at 6 am, 12 pm, 4 pm, 12am. Whats wrong here?